# picture source и media запросы

Tags: html, img

Есть 6 картинок.
3шт в формате webp. 3шт в формате png.

Для старых версий ios/macOs был выбран тег picture. Если не поддерживается формат webp ---> будет загружена png.

Как вывести картинку под нужно разрешение браузера?

Cейчас выводится всегда картинка под названием "3Без имени.png".

```html
<picture>
      <source type="image/webp" media="(min-width: 1300px)" srcset="../Без имени.webp">
      <source type="image/webp" media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="../2Без имени.webp">
      <source type="image/webp" srcset="../3Без имени.webp">

      <source media="(min-width: 1300px)" srcset="../Без имени.png">
      <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="../2Без имени.png">
      <img src=" ../3Без имени.png" alt="TODO">
</picture>
```